# What happens to IP3 molecules after release from IP3 receptors?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cell-signaling

IP<sub>3</sub> molecules bind to IP<sub>3</sub> receptors and open up the calcium channels on the endoplasmic reticulum. I am wondering what happens to IP<sub>3</sub> molecules after they have been released from the IP<sub>3</sub> receptor? Do they remain as IP<sub>3</sub> molecules, or do they break down? Do they have any purpose after they have been released, and perhaps after been broken down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All biomolecules are eventually broken down. This process is called turnover. Since inositol is a signalling molecule it is necessary to remove in order to terminate the signal, despite adaptive mechanism in the ER calcium channels.

IP3 is generally dephosphorylated by a family of phosphatase enzymes called inositol polyphosphate phosphatases. After dephosphorylation, the inositol can be recycled into the membrane by phosphatidyl-inositol synthase.

Reference:

[The IUPHAR/BPS Guide to PHARMACOLOGY](http://www.guidetopharmacology.org/GRAC/FamilyDisplayForward?familyId=245) <sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> *I'm citing this website instead of a research article because apart from citing the original research articles, it also has other informative links about the enzymes and the substrate molecules. It is also from a very reliable source.*

Comment: thank you so much @wysiwyg By the way, how do we know the lifetime of such signalling molecules.

Comment: @nashynash There are different assays by which it can be found out. One way is to label the metabolite using an isotope (like ¹³C) and track the loss of radioisotope in the sample using mass spectrometry or NMR. In this case the "lifetime" depends on the phosphorylated state of inositol - so the phosphorous has to be labelled instead of carbon.